# how to connect linux mint to windows 10 using LAN cable?

Tags: windows, linux-mint, lan

Please tell me how to connect mint to windows using LAN cable. I am using mint 18.3  cinnamon 64-bit and gave access to LAN cable. My friend has windows 10 and we are having trouble sharing files using LAN. I searched some methods nut none of them were specific to our problem

Comment: Is your situation two standalone computers in close proximity that you want to connect with a cable, or can both be connected to a network?  By LAN cable, are you referring to a standard Ethernet cable?  What have you already tried, and in what way did they not work (what were the exact symptoms)?  Without knowing that, people will suggest the same things you already tried unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the two computers using a patch cable or two patch cables and an Ethernet switch (you have one built into your internet router) between them. As to the *type* of cable you'll need for a direct connection (no switch) - first try a straight one; if one of the computers is capable of autoswitching between normal and crossed-over configuration on the network adapter itself then a crossover cable won't be required. If neither computer is auto-crossover compatible, a crossover cable will be required. You'll know if your computers aren't crossover enabled because the light indicating a link is established won't light up. This light is usually adjacent the ethernet socket

If your computers are connected to a router they should get an ip address each themselves. If connected with a crossover cable they won't get an ip, or they may take some time and then both settle on an automatic IP address in the 169.254 range which will also suffice. If they don't then manually give one an ip of 192.168.0.1 and the other an ip of 192.168.0.2

Share some files on the windows machine using file sharing (right click the file or folder, choose share with..) and then refer to this SE network page for info on how to connect the Linux box to the SMB share created by windows: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287362/mount-samba-in-linux-mint

Alternatively, connect both machines to the internet, download by sync (aka resilio sync) to both machines, select the folder to share on one machine and type the secret phrase into the other machine. The files in the folder will be synced to the other machine. Changes are mirrored in both directions. This method burns more disk space but gives faster access to files and allows access even when one machine is off. It also works like a backup if these are important files, as both machines have to die to lose the data

Comment: _"You cannot get two computers to talk by connecting them directly with a straight cable, only a crossover cable"_ – um, this hasn't been true for well over a decade now? Many computers already had Auto-MDIX in the 2000s and it's practically unavoidable with Gigabit Ethernet.

Comment: As @grawity mentioned, Crossover cables are only required on 10/100 ethernet, not gigabit [10/100/1000], as it supports auto-negotiation.

Comment: I connected two PCs with windows though a cable to transfer some files. Literally only the cable between them.